# safe to delete windows defender scan and definition updates folders? Windows 7,8,8.1

Tags: windows, windows-defender

It looks like WD keeps a history of all scans and keep older definition files.
Is it ok to delete the **content** of these two folder and let WD rebuild their content.

Anyway to disable WD to keep accumulating this history scans and delete old definitions?

I have already tried the free disk space function on Windows 8.1, but it didn't delete these WD files

Comment: @Ramhound don't you just need the latest update? Doesn't the latest include the previous ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of threads to find in Google about this subject. It doesn't seem like Microsoft is willing to document this, but many people have just done it and I don't see any complaints. Should be safe enough.

If you want to be sure, just create a restore point, move all files to a temporary folder, reboot machine, update Windows and Windows Defender, reboot again and see if:

- everything still works (hint: you can try to download the EICAR antivirus test file from http://www.eicar.org/ to check the functionality of any antivirus application - this is a **safe** testfile that must be recognised as a virus by all AV's)
- all that data gets gets re-downloaded, in which case it probably doesn't make much sense to delete it  :)

Good luck.

Comment: thanks for the feedback, it is true that there are many threads but the majority are asking how to uninstall defender and thus want to remove those folders, I don't want to uninstall defender